# Select a UITableViewCell programmatically if it contains cgrect

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView. I have an image like an arrow beside the tableview.

I have to check whether the arrow is intersecting with a particular cell so that I can programatically select that cell. How do I do this?

**I dont have a problem in the type of selection of the cell/row but having problems detecting whether the arrow is on a particular row.**

I have written this code but not working :

```
NSArray *paths = [tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];

for (NSIndexPath *path in paths)
{
    CGRect myRect = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    CGRect myRect1 = CGRectMake(-12, 234, 55, 52);
    
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(myRect1, myRect))
    {
        // Also tried [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
        cell.selected = YES;
        NSLog(@"\n \n \n myrect = %@ myrect1 = %@ , index = %@ \n \n ", NSStringFromCGRect(myRect),NSStringFromCGRect(myRect1), indexPath);
    }
    else
    {
        cell.selected = NO;
    }
}
```

Images shows what I want to achieve and not whats existing.

[image][image]

Comment: try calling 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath:' programmatically.

Comment: did that.. doesn't work...

Comment: could you please show the code that you have in that 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath' ? And also place a breakpoint there to be sure it gets called.

Comment: ok.. First of all the selection itself is not happening. If i was not clear, the selection of a cell has to happen depending on which cell is the arrow placed on. the selection is not happening by touching a particular cell. So there's no question of didSelectRowAtIndexPath being called here..

Comment: 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath' will come into the picture after selecting a particular row.

Comment: Can i just ask for curosity, why you want to do that.

Comment: this is just a skeleton module that will be customised to something else later..

Comment: Oh...ok...I thought the images were showing what you currently have. Thanks for the edit. I'll try to find a solution and if I do , I 'll post. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer.. Posting the code

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView 
{

      NSArray *paths = [tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];

      for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in paths) 
      {

          CGRect myRect = [tableView convertRect:[tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] toView:[tableView superview]];
          CGRect myRect1 = CGRectMake(-12, 236, 20, 30);

          if (CGRectIntersectsRect(myRect1, myRect) && notSelected == FALSE) 
          {

               notSelected = TRUE;
              [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];

           }
           else
           {

                notSelected = FALSE;
                [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
            }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok...for the problem with the arrow... I think the table is returning the rectangle for each row IN REGARDS to the table's frame. So I think you need to do this:

```
for (NSIndexPath *path in paths) 
{

    CGRect myRect = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    CGRect myRect1 = CGRectMake(-12, 234, 55, 52);

    myRect.origin.x += tableView.frame.origin.x;
    myRect.origin.y += tableView.frame.origin.y;

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(myRect1, myRect)) 
    {
        //selection code here
    }
    else
    {
        // whatever you want
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks george.. I guess i have found an answer.. Will keep this in mind though if any prob occurs..